# EditText и его значение

Tags: android, textview, edittext

Есть простейший код:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
   Button B1;
   EditText et;
   TextView tv;
   String s;


    @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
B1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.B1);
et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et);
tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv);

tv.setText(et.getText().toString()); }}
```

Но, как и предполагалось, код не работает, поэтому я решил сделать присвоение значения строке s в onClick:

```
    public void onClick(View v) {
 switch (v.getId()) {
case R.id.B1:
s = et.getText().toString();
break;}}
```

И только потом использовать полученную строку:

```
tv.setText(s);
```

Но и это не помогло. Прошу, помогите мне такому непонимающиму.

P.S. а возможно ли как-нибудь "легально" передать значения переменных из onClick в onCreate?

Comment: _"легально" передать_ никак - `onCreate` вызывается первым, а `onClick` когда-нибудь потом, когда нажмут на кнопку. Но вы можете вставить текст в `TextView` в самом `onClick`

Comment: в onClick сразу передавай полученную строку на виджет : `tv.setText(et.getText().toString();` а не в какую то переменную сохраняй

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> P.S. а возможно ли как-нибудь "легально" передать значения переменных из onClick в onCreate?

Очевидно, Вам не хватает фундаментальных знаний по Android SDK, а именно, знаний о жизненном цикле Activity. Без них Вам будет очень тяжело.

Как уже упомянул woesss в своём комментарии, метод onCreate() вызывается всего один раз, при создании активности, onClick() - после каждого клика.

Если же Вы хотите, чтобы TextView отображал текущее содержимое EditText, рекомендую воспользоваться методом addTextChangedListener у Вашего элемента EditText. Пример:

```
TextWatcher textWatcher= new TextWatcher() {
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) { 

    }
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after){ 

    }
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
        tv.setText(et.getText().toString());
    }
};

et.addTextChangedListener(textWatcher);
```

Comment: Именно это мне и нужно - проверять, какой длины введенное слово (для этого, ведь, это слово надо получить).